# windows service not add data to database after release

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I`m new to ASP.Net and I need to create windows service for adding data to mssql database but the problem is my code is work in visual studio before release after I release its not adding data to database

```
        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConfig"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection oSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        oSqlConnection.Open();

        string insertText = @"INSERT INTO csvs(Agency,Status) VALUES ('Tst','0')";
        using (var command2 = new SqlCommand(insertText, oSqlConnection))
        {
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

this is my app.config file

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBConfig" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: So when you release, what is the identity of the app pool? Does that principal have access to your db? do you have any exception logging? Are there any logs in the eventvwr?

Comment: It is a windows service that the OP refers to, thus has nothing to do with IIS app pools. You are using windows integrated security, so the account under which your service is running must have access to the database. Unless you specify the username and password explicitly in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the security for default app pool using User Mapping and it's working.

Comment: I have same issue